# Relay logs to elasticsearch from fluentd by event type

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, fluentd

I have json logs like below:

```
{"event": "{"eventType": "pageview","userId": "2122334"}"}
{"event": "{"eventType": "reload","userId": "2122334"}"}
```

I need to relay events to separate elasticsearch indices base on their eventType. I am confused in using label, patterns in rules and etc in fluentd.

One way is to label the events by type and then to send to elasticsearch different indices. But I cannot find an example how to do this.

Any help appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: what do you want to do, I think basically you can use parser to fetch the specific key from records.

Answer (score 0):

Given your logs are JSON formatted, you'll have something like this in your source section:

```
  <parse>
    @type json
    time_key $.log.myTimeField  # optional, just for you to see how to retrieve keys from json.
    keep_time_key true   # optional
  </parse>
```

Then you can have a match like this:

```
  <match **>
    @type copy
    <store>
      @type elasticsearch
      host 127.0.0.1
      port 9200
      index_name logs.${myKey}
      include_tag_key true
      <buffer tag, myKey>
        flush_at_shutdown true
        flush_mode immediate
        flush_thread_count 8
      </buffer>
    </store>
  </match>
```

Note you'll need the buffer section. This example is simple, maybe you could try something like this, to fit your needs:

index_name logs.${event["eventType"]}

I know this is an old question, but hopefully helps somehow. Good luck!